# cakephp deal with passing wrong parameter in url

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

How can i deal with correct base url with wrong parameter?

Cakephp if u pass wrong controller or action name, it will lead to 404 page.
But if i enter correct controller/action name with wrong parameter, how can i deal with this kind of case.

Example:

correct:   `http://localhost/controller/action?params=123`
wrong: `http://localhost/controller/action?par23=123`

par23 is wrong name. in this case i want to redirect to some pages like 404 page. is there any method or configuration i do not need to check parameter in controller and redirect to some page everytime.

thank you

Comment: Is there a reason why you use "normal" query strings, not Cake's format of `/controller/action/param1/param2` or the named param way `/controller/action/name1:value1/name2:value2`?

Comment: not special reason. personal preference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to check this manually in your controller.

Instead of looking for any extra *wrong* param, I would simply check if your *needed* params are there. If not, you can throw an exception.

This is how Cake's baked code does it:

```
// MyModelController.php
public function view($id = null) {
        $this->MyModel->id = $id;
        if (!$this->MyModel->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid thing'));
        }

        // ...
}
```

So here, an ID is needed. If it is not given (default value `null`) or no record with this Id exists, an Exception that results in a 404 is thrown.

Note that this has an extra benefit: It is not only covering the case where a param is missing, it also correctly returns an error if the param is present but references a non-existent item by `$id`.

Comment: good point. so there is not any alternative way do this by configuration?

Comment: Cake will give you a 404 if no route matches your request. But you should not only check if the parameter is present, but also if the referenced item exists. This is what the above code does. You could try to implement this in a more generic way in your AppController, if you use similar params for all your models.