# cakephp url append invalid parameter But still work. Should be 404 page not found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I find a problem when i develop application via cakephp.

for example:  my url is `http://localhost/controller/view/id` this is working fine.

BUT, when i append more invalid parameter, it still works,

like `http://localhost/controller/view/id/adfasd/adfasdf/asdfasdf/asdfasdf`

It should show up 404 page not found.

Shall i need to use $this->passedArgs to check pass parameter manually in controller then throw exception? Or is there any configuration?

How can i deal with this case

Thank you

Comment: What is your use case ? `/adfasd/adfasdf/asdfasdf/asdfasdf` are additional parameters that are passed to your action but are just not used. Why would you care of them ? It is similar to any website that uses standard parameters such as `param1=value&param2=value`. You can add some random parameters and its doesn't raise any exception. For instance http://www.google.com/?foo=bar&john=doe works without any problem.

Comment: thank you for reply @nIcO coz when i use some crawler application, crawler my website. i found some invalid parameter still ok， but i test out other framework dont have this problem, they will show 404 page. any idea?

Comment: @nIcO lets say if u input google.com/abc/cba that will cause error right ?

Comment: Yes http://www.google.com/abc/abc fails. But still, I don't understand why you bother of urls that do work. You won't generate random urls on your website. Do you ? So ok, if anybody wants to add let's say `/adfasd/adfasdf/` at the end of your website urls, it still works. And so what ? Is it really a problem ?

Comment: @nIcO well u right. its not real a problem. but just think if i can do better to fix.  say if other framework can done that why not cake? thank you for ur time! ；）

Comment: o btw @nIcO r u author of acl plugin for cake？ awesome job for acl plugin. our project is using. awesome job big thank you for ur contribution

Comment: Yes I am :-) thanks for your congrats

Answer (score 1):

You should first look here [Cakephp, Routing-Named params](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#controlling-named-parameters) to find out how to properly use them.

As you should add which one to use, you should also add a regex to your id in the route.
Also when sending the data to an action you should throw the exception there like it is explained here: [cakephp deal with passing wrong parameter in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926615/cakephp-deal-with-passing-wrong-parameter-in-url)

Comment: so i have to add regex for each of url manually? yes i did throw exception when some data is not found. but im my case as i explain above. throw exception cannot solve properly